# Добавление UserControl-ов по центру FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

При добавлении `UserControl-ов` в `FlowLayoutPanel`, они прижимаются к левому краю.

А как сделать так, что-бы они размещались по центру ?

И в случае, если по ширине окна помещается 2 `UserControl-а`, то нужно что бы они тоже были по центру.

Пересмотрев и почитав из того что есть на RU, судя по всему, нет подобного свойства в самой `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Нужно подобное реализовывать с помощью других элементов ?

Щас подумал... что наверно, `FlowLayoutPanel` можно запихнуть в `TableLayoutPanel` из 3-х резиновых столбцов.

Или как то иначе ?

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel в WPF?

Comment: @VladD, нет - в WinForms, WPF метку указал, так как казалось, что пользователи WPF, могут знать WinForms. Могу убрать метку, если сбивает с толку.

Comment: Если пользователи WPF знают WinForms, то ничто не мешает им просматривать вопросы по этой метке. Метки должны соответствовать контексту вопроса, не нужно засорять их.

Comment: Нет, FLP такого не умеет. В формах вообще не очень хорошо с динамической компоновкой, реализованы только совсем базовые вещи вроде FLP и TLP, остальные красивости надо делать руками аккуратно обходя острые углы и уворачиваясь от реактивных тараканов. Но при должном упорстве вполне можно сделать "конфетку" из м... исходного сырья